# How to put a time stamp while copying files in the for loop inside the batch file

Tags: file, loops, scripting, batch-file, timestamp

Help please! I am new to the batch files and have a very specific question. I am trying to copy many files in multiple subdirectories into a single directory via a for loop and in the meantime attache a timestamp to each name (because all the files have the same name). I am using the system variable time and parsing it inside the loop, but the local variables inside the loop get assigned garbage. I already know about delayed expansion and using ! sign instead of %, but that doesnt help me. here is the code:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set counter=1
echo in the beginning the counter is "%counter%"
:loop
for /r "c:\users\wimdu\dropbox\wimdu CRM\emarsys reports - campaigns" %%f in (bounce*.*) do (
set a = %time::=%
echo in loop a equals "!a!"
echo the time is !time!
set b=!a:,=!

copy /y "%%f" c:\users\wimdu\documents\bouncehandling\bouncecsvfiles\%b%.csv
)
EndLocal
```

So,  basically the names of the files would be 10151821.csv, for instance (time stamp including milliseconds). ideally it would be the original filename (bounces) concatenated with time stamp with .csv extension. I have tried everything but with the timestamp nothing seems to work, a just does not get assigned correctly. And then b as well . I do not know how to parse a and then assign it to b within !! signs. Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems.
You didn't set "a" as you append a space, you set "a ".
And you always use the same time, as %time% will be expanded only once while parsing the block:.
The same problem you get with %b%.
Change both to delayed expansion and it could work.

Comment: i tried that too, when i am assigning a=!time! it does garbage as well, and then in the file path to save !b! is not read as value, rather as string "!b!" or other weird things.

Comment: ok, now i have figured it out, thank you, your answer helped me to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Agree with [@jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769612/how-to-put-a-time-stamp-while-copying-files-in-the-for-loop-inside-the-batch-fil/7770664#7770664) on all the points, however there may be another problem. Depending on your locale, the result of `%time%` may contain a leading space when the current time is before 10 in the morning. If that is so, the target path in your `COPY` command gets split, since it is not enclosed in double quotes. As a result, the command becomes syntactically incorrect.

So, if you fix all the issues mentioned so far, your script should work without any problem. At least a simplified version of your script worked for me. Here's how I tested it:

First, I created a simple setup on my computer:

```
MKDIR C:\tests\source
MKDIR C:\tests\target
```

then copied several random files of moderate size to the `C:\tests\source` folder and ran the following script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /R "C:\tests\source" %%f IN (*) DO (
  SET a=!time::=!
  SET a=!a:,=!
  COPY /Y "%%f" "\!a!"
)
```

And this is what appeared in `C:\tests\target` as a result:

```
_1395459
_1395470
_1395639
```

I should point out that `_` is actually a space, because on my computer the result of `%time%` indeed contains a leading space at this hour, which is between midnight and 10 a.m. in this part of the world. Anyway, my main point is, the script I posted above (which, I stress, is basically the same as yours) has worked for me.